# Java Interface methods throws exception

Tags: java, exception

My method takes as input an Interface. I want to ensure that all the methods in the interface are defined with a "throws RemoteException". How can I check that?

Comment: where do you want to check it? e.g. compilation time, unit test, ...

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ues instanceof.  For example :

```
if ( myObject instanceof IMyInterface ) then { 
    ... Log Success ... 
} 
else { 
    ... Log Failure ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the `class` of the `interface` being passed (not of the `Object` which implements the required `interface`), then something like this would work; comments in code explaining steps.

```
public boolean matchesExpectation(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (!clazz.isInterface()) {
        // Class isn't an interface
        return false;
    }
    // Class is an interface, check all the methods.
    methodSearch:
    for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods() {
        for (Class<?> exceptionClass : method.getExceptionTypes()) {
            if (RemoteException.class.isAssignableFrom(exceptionClass)) {
                // Check the next method.
                continue methodSearch;
            }
        }
        // Exception is not thrown by this method.
        return false;
    }
    // Every method declared expected exception.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ensure that all the methods in the interface are defined with a "throws RemoteException". How can I check that?

Lets assume that you want to check this at compile time<sup>1</sup>.

The Java language does not directly support this kind of thing.  However, you *could* implement it using a third-party static code checker like PMD as follows:

- Define a custom annotation that you can attach to interfaces; e.g. `@AllMethodsThrowRMIE`
- Define a custom PMD rule that looks for interfaces with this annotation and checks that they meet the required criteria.

You could potentially do the same thing with a custom annotation processor.

---

However, before embarking on this (non-trivial) development effort, I would ask myself if the payoff was worth the effort.

---

<sup>1 - If you do it at runtime, then you have the possibility that your service won't start because you slipped up with your testing regime.  But you might want *both compile time and runtime* checking ...</sup>